# Nyquist plot for arbitrary path

Tags: control-theory

Suppose we have the following transfer function:

$G(s) = K \frac{s+3}{s(s+1)}$

Given the above Nyquist path[image]

I want to sketch Nyquist plot. By using the Nyquist plot rules, I made the following sketch:

[image]

According to Nyquist plot, there is counter-clockwise encirclement of $-1$.

$N = P - Z$

where $P$ and $Z$ are the number of open loop and closed loop poles enclosed by the path, respectively. Since there is CCW encirclement of $-1$, then $N = 1$. There is also $1$ open loop poles which is enclosed by the path, so $P = 1$. According to this information, the number of closed loop poles $Z$ is zero. But if you quickly sketch a root locus, we see that this is not true. Can you help me out for finding my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a Nyquist plot using a different contour than the one encircling the right half plane, then the meaning of the variables in the equation $N=P-Z$ changes. Namely, those variables represent the number of poles/zeros that lie inside the used contour.

If you calculate the closed poles for $K=1$, by solving $s^2+2s+3=0$, yields $s=-1\pm\,i\sqrt{2}$, which lies outside the the selected contour.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about for $K = 10$? The roots in this case $-5+1.41j$ and $-5-1.41j$ which are inside the contour.

Comment: @eet Did you also draw the Nyquist plot using that value of $K$ and check the encirclements again?

Comment: I think adjustment of $K$ will only shrink or expand the nyquist plot. Since there is no intersection with the real axis, no matter what we set for $K$, there will one encirclement of $-1$.

Comment: @eet I have double checked your contour by plotting it with some code and noticed that your sketch is wrong. Namely, the resulting Nyquist plot crosses the negative real line a total of four times (including the two times near zero and infinity). Those other two point at which it crosses the negative real line can be moved with $K$ and can thus change the number of encirclements of minus one.

Comment: You are right, I realized my mistake. thank you.